# SFMC Rest API and Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I hope I'm not over-complicating this, but it seems like a lot of work to send an email out of SFMC.

My goal is to be able to send emails from SFMC based on certain SF field changes. E.g. Lead status changes from X to Y, lead gets a personalized email.

So far I've set up a data extension and template, then a triggered email that references the data extension and email template. Now I can hit this endpoint:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/bd3d918e-c22e-e411-ad6f-38eaa791d321/send

with this json:

```
{
    "To": {
        "subscriberKey": "x@x.com",
        "address": "x@x.com",

    }
}
```

and I see this error:

```
[{"messageErrorStatus":"There are required data extension fields missing for the subscriber"}]}
```

Presumably, I need to reference the extension fields in the JSON, I"m just not sure of the syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that you can send this email without the trigger, just with a send within the application?

Comment: Just a little off topic note but if you send an email out using the Exact Target API and NOT from Exacttarget looking at Salesforce you don't get the activity coming back from Exacttarget saying that the user has opened the email etc. (Learnt this to my cost)

Comment: Hey Francis, not sure exactly what you're saying. You mean you can't get activity records in SF? That's fine, our marketing team will be reviewing from with in ET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished this way...or you can make the fields on your Data Extension "Nullable" if you do not want to pass them as values on your call.

```
"To": {
        "Address": "test@test.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "test@test.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "DEFieldName1": "VALUEHERE",
                "DEFieldName2": "VALUEHERE",
                "DEFieldName3": "VALUEHERE"
 }
```

Details can be found here as well:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html